# Redirect after android login activity

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-studio

I have created a login activity from [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_login_screen.htm).
But I have no idea how to redirect to my main activity after the login process has succeeded.

Here is the login.java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login extends Activity {

private EditText  username=null;
private EditText  password=null;
private TextView attempts;
private Button login;
int counter = 3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

public void login(View view){
    if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
            password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        counter--;
        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        if(counter==0){
            login.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
        password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(login.this, your_new_activity_name.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Also ensure that the new activity is registered in the AndroidManifest file.

In the sample code below, change `.MainMenu` with your_new_activity_name.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainMenu"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

This URL will help you learn.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'm really impressed with how fast you answered! Working like a bullet.